# Finding binaries of Geonode for Windows

Tags: geonode

I want to download Geonode binaries for Windows and unfortunately its a while that all geonode.org download links for Windows doesn't work. So how can I download or find geonode-2.6.x or higher?

Comment: You may need to use docker

Answer (score 1):

[Cartoview](https://cartoview.net/) is providing a windows installation for geonode,
see this [discussion](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/issues/4050#issuecomment-501280244)